# Nodemailer / Mailgun Sender option

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, mailgun, nodemailer

Im using Nodemailer (https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) and mailgun in my Node.js application.

What im trying to do is specify the "sender" in the mail. I am sending the email like this:

```
var auth = {
    auth: {
        api_key: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY,
        domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN
    }
}

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(mailgunTransport(auth));

var recipients = process.env.MAILGUN_RECIPIENTS;

    var mail = {
        from: contactPerson.firstName + " " + contactPerson.lastName + " " + "<" + contactPerson.email + ">",
        to: recipients,
        subject: "Innspill til bredbåndsutbygging",
        text: message
    }

    transport.sendMail(mail, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error occurred!");
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Email sendt!");
            console.log(info);
        }
    });
```

In gmail it displays as:
From: **Firstname Lastname** < test@example.com >

For my client it displays as: 
From: job=live.no@mg.lillesand.com [mailto:job=live.no@mg.lillesand.com]

I suspect it has something to do with the "Sender" parameter in the email header.

From the Nodemailer docs it says

> sender - An e-mail address that will appear on the Sender: field
>   (always prefer from if you're not sure which one to use)

I tried setting the sender option to no avail.

```
var mail = {
    sender: contactPerson.email,
    from: contactPerson.firstName + " " + contactPerson.lastName + " " + "<" + contactPerson.email + ">",
    to: recipients,
    subject: "Innspill til bredbåndsutbygging",
    text: message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually wanted to add a comment, but don't have enough reputation.
I wanted to give you some tips where to look for, because I am not sure what kind of questions you have there.

Did you check the client side JS-file for any misplaced quotes, that could be interpreted for one service but not for the other?

Also check what kind of encoding you are using. On client if you have a form you can set `XMLHttpRequest().setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`
You can encode on the server side as well, using certain node modules like express.
Note, that you can display html and plain text.
html will ignore escape signs like \n

I am almost certain that your problems lies in the configuration of Mailgun. In my very hard learning I have not encountered your display problem.

I hope it helps.